# JQuery "floating" tab like GetSatisfaction

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I want to create a tab/widget/thingymajiggy like the feedback-thing in this picture:

[image]

That behaves like [this](http://getsatisfaction.com/widgets). I just need to redirect on click, I don't need all the other stuff.

I have been unable to find a JQuery plugin, that does this - but maybe I just don't know the correct term.

...And yes, I could just pillage getsatisfaction, but I would much rather have a nice tried and tested JQuery plugin.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't really need Javascript for this. This is achieved by giving an element a position of `fixed`:

```
<a id="floating_link" href="whatever.html">Go Somewhere</a>

#floating_link {
     position: fixed;
     right: 0;
     top: 400px;
     display: block;
     width: 50px;
     height: 125px;
     text-indent: -10000px;
     background-image: url(/my/image.jpg);
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Unfortunately, IE6 doesn't support `fixed`. You can get around that by using [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryFixedPositionPlugin).

If you don't care about IE6, then you can just use the above. The only difference is that IE6 will treat it as an absolute element (so it won't scroll down with the page, which isn't a big deal)

[Here is an example of it at work](http://jsbin.com/ometu). As you can see the entire area is clickable.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. How can I make the entire content of the #floating_link clickable? With just an a-href, if possible. I can surround the div by an a-tag, but nesting divs inside anchors seems very dirty.

Comment: As it is right now the entire link should be clickable. What behavior are you getting?

Comment: I completely overlooked the fact that you had actually also inserted a link, sorry. It works perfect, thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem. I added a live example in anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a great reference as well: http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html